# Where to buy specific types of paper?

Tags: business, resource-recommendations, print-production, design-process, packaging

I am currently in the process of making printing out flyers and having them professionally cut.

But before i need to know exactly where to buy them.
I know I need either 80# matte text paper or 100# coated text (we don't the flyers to be too glossy).

I looked up those grade of papers online and so far only the Paper Mill Store offers them. Anyone has any suggestions about where to physically buy those? 
I'm in the Washington DC Metropolitan area.

I have a Xerox Phaser 7400, so I know that weight is supported by the printer. I want to print them at the office then take have the flyers professionally cut. Just trying to minimize the costs as much as possible. I'm going with 250 flyers or more for 4 per page.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a shopping question [which is off topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158810/215485)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this paper stock at my local Staples (South Florida) I would call your local Staples and ask.

Comment: @KimieMbongo Start with local office supply sources such as Staples, mentioned here. Then, if they can't help you, try stationery supply. Finally, you might find the stock you need from the printer or wherever you will have your paper cut. All these things tend to share a roof. Note that the kind of paper your printer (the person) has might not have the finish that your printer (the thing) needs for optimal appearance.

Answer (score 1):

> professionally cut

The cut is just a step in the process.

Are you going to **print** them professionally? Aka offset sheeted print? Digitally printed? Or are you going to print it at your office/home?.

If you are not very experienced, I would not buy the paper by myself, because you are risking that your print system is not compatible with the paper you are providing. Ink absorption, durability, color reproduction, etc.

The matt finish can be done on a glossy paper with a varnish for example. So It is better that you talk to your print provider and see the options with them.

Comment: I have a Xerox Phaser 7400, so I know that weight is supported by the printer. I want to print them at the office then take have the flyers professionally cut. Just trying to minimize the costs as much as possible. I'm going with 250 flyers or more for 4 per page.